# TypeError cannot unpack non-iterable float object in centered average algorithm Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, data-structures

I have a **Type Error** from **centered average** algorithm in Python. this is my code

```
def calc_centered_average(numbers):
    sorted_list = sorted(numbers)
    return sum(sorted_list[1:-1])/(len(numbers)-2)
    # return subnumbers, centered_average


numbers = [1, 4, 5, 6, 100]
sublist, cavg = calc_centered_average(numbers)
print(f"The centered average of {numbers} is {cavg} (based on {sublist}).")
```

Comment: Please post a small sample data so we can try to replicate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you are returning one value instead of two in your function. Here is the correct way that I assume you should do it:

```py
def calc_centered_average(numbers):
    sorted_list = sorted(numbers)
    subnumbers = sorted_list[1:-1]
    centered_average = sum(subnumbers)/(len(numbers)-2)
    return subnumbers, centered_average


numbers = [1, 4, 5, 6, 100]
sublist, cavg = calc_centered_average(numbers)
print(f"The centered average of {numbers} is {cavg} (based on {sublist}).")
```